# How do I make MVC to sign out a logged in user?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, login-control

I understand that when a user logs in to MVC webapp (when runtime executes `FormsAuthentication.SignIn(..)`), that user receiver a cookie and continues to work with the site with that cookie.

However the user can login again, from incognito window or another PC and get **access to the site from both places simultaneously**. I would like to **prevent him** from doing that.

I believe that the solution of this issue lies somewhere close, however nethier googling nor digging into MVC Forms Authentication classes provided me nothing I could work with.

So how do I forcibly sign off the last user login info (I believe it is a cookie stored inside a web server, I might be wrong) when **that** user successefully attempts to login in somewhere new place?

Comment: Cookies are stored at Client side not Server

Comment: @HarisHasan how come in that case the server knows which cookie is valid and which one is not?

Comment: because they have a expiry date

Comment: Also they are encrypted with the servers MachineKey, so if decryption fails it knows the cookies isn't valid or at least not for this server. Notice: This is not the case for every cookie, but for the default FormsAuthentication cookie it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way you can do that, is by storing the user login in information in a table. So when the user tries to log in again, you can verify weather he is logged in some where else by quering the table. Once the user logs out, delete rows from the table.

Remember you would not be able to do anything with the help of cookies. Cookies will just contain form authentication ticket, which would be used by authentication module to verify whether the coming request is authenticated or not. And since the calls are stateless you can not decided anything just by looking at the cookie

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement

```
Application_AuthenticateRequest
```

in your global.asax file an validate that the user identity is still correct. e.g. you need to keep track of all session related to the user and which clients he used. You can then respond with a cookie reset in the mentioned method, if you want to sign out the user.

Comment: Cannot implement it since I cannot find the virtual method definition.

Comment: Its not an override, you just need to define that function.

See:
`public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            ......
        }

        protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest()
        {
            ......
        }
    }`

You don't override Application_Start either.